# How to change listview font color without using custom listview?

Tags: android

How to Change Listview Color withour using custom listview?

In my application the background is white so listview's font is not display.

Comment: you meant to say that change the all Text View Color to any one particular color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have search for your solution and finally i get that you can not change text color in list view without customize it so please note that.

Comment: If this will help you than just vote it up and please if you find any solution regard How to Change Listview Color withour using custom listview ? than answer me.

Answer (score 0):

either remove listview background or use customAdapter .

Answer (score 0):

you can change the listview font color by overriding the `getview()`method of a default listview adapter such as cursor adapter or simple cursor adapter
.